# Erro "A conexão subjacente estava fechada" em requisição REST HttpClient C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, rest, httpclient

Estou fazendo uma integração em REST com C# utilizado HttpClient, na maioria das vezes os dados foram enviados com sucesso, porem fui investigar o porque alguns estavem retornando com erro, descobri que o que eles tinham em comum, era que o JSON enviado era um pouco maior dos que os demais (possuia mais dados), descobri em alguns fóruns que isto é um BUG recorrente do .NET e tentei algumas soluções apontadas, como por exemplo setar o Keep-Alive no cabeçalho da requisição, e tambem trocar a versão do HTTP para 1.0, ambas sem sucesso.

O erro retornado é este:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a solicitação. ---> System.Net.WebException: A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um recebimento. ---> System.IO.IOException: Não é possível ler os dados da conexão de transporte: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto
   em System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Net.PooledStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Net.Connection.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha de exceções internas ---
   em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

Abaixo trecho do código onde faço a requisição:

````
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
        MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "192.168.77.23:4002";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Action", metodo);

        //Adicionado aqui para ver se persiste conexão - segundo solução apontada em alguns 
        fóruns
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "5000");      

        var content = new StringContent(req, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");                                                     

        try
        {                   

         HttpResponseMessage res = new HttpResponseMessage();

       // Trocada versão do HTTP segundo solução apontada em alguns fóruns
       res.Version = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;

       res = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl + req, content);                                                                  

       res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
       string resContent = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
       dynamic resultado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resContent);       

       string erro = resultado.Header.Error;

    ```
````

Comment: APIs por segurança negam requisições que possuem json muito grande. É bem provável que o host 192.168.77.23 esteja bloqueando esse seu request. Então você não vai resolver o problema no request, e sim na API que recebe. Se a API for de terceiros, contate eles. Se a API for sua, você pode configurar o tamanho padrão limite e aumentar ele, por mais que isso vai abrir sua API a ter outros problemas de segurança e performance.

Comment: Interessante, a API é de terceiros, quando envio o JSON do meu request para eles, eles conseguem efetuar a inclusão sem problemas, inclusive me mandam o retorno da api com sucesso, pesquisando achei outros casos dizendo que é um BUG do .NET por isso parti para esse caminho, se fosse algo no servidor deles sera que eles não teriam problema tambem?

Comment: Poderia ter, acho que o caminho a seguir agora seria contatar eles e verificar se eles possuem um log para ver qual é o verdadeiro problema.

Comment: O tamanho e/ou tempo de resposta também aumenta consoante o tamanho do objeto enviado?

Comment: não, é o mesmo tempo de uma requisição que volta com sucesso, acho que o problema é que a requisição começa a demorar um pouco mais e algo corta a conexão de forma abrupta, porém quando eles fazem a requisição na linguagem e ambiente que trabalham da certo, vou tentar fazer com o POSTMAN para testar..